# Cross-Origin Request Blocked while working with go

Tags: go, cors, fetch-api

I am working with JavaScript frontend and go backend. I created an API using go gin framework.

My `main.go` is :

```
func main() {

  router := gin.Default()
  router.GET("/", getBasicBlogInfo)

  router.Use(cors.Default())
  err := router.Run("localhost:8080")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Unable to run the server.")
  }

}
```

Now in my `index.js`

```
fetch('localhost:8080')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

However I am getting a CORS-origin Request block error.

The error I got is :

```
Error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

and the CORS one is:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/. (Reason: CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the error? Perhaps with a screenshot of such error. Did you check the complete request/response via chrome inspect (network tab)?

Comment: The error most likely stems from your omission of the URL scheme in your client code. Try `fetch('http://localhost:8080')` instead. And please always include the relevant error message in your question.

Comment: The question associated above does not solve this problem, So I would like to reopen the question!!

Answer (score -1):

```
import "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"

// r.Use(AllowAll())
func AllowAll() gin.HandlerFunc{
    cfg := cors.Config{
        AllowMethods:     []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    }

    cfg.AllowAllOrigins = true
    return cors.New(cfg)
}
```